# Implicitly reference underlying type for nested generics

Tags: kotlin, generics

Trying to implement a generic initializer for a type which wraps another generic type.

Having this reverse mapper for a generic kind of enum

```
class SerializableEnumMapper<V, T>(
    enumValues: Array<T>
) where T : Enum<T>, T: SerializableEnum<V> {

    private val mapEnum: Map<V, T> = 
        mutableMapOf<V, T>().apply {
            enumValues.forEach {
                this[it.rawValue] = it
            }
        }

    fun getEnum(value: V): T? = mapEnum[value]
}
```

Where `SerializableEnum` is a generic interface to provide a raw value.

```
interface SerializableEnum<T> {
    val rawValue: T
}
```

Now, for the following enum:

```
enum class SomeEnum(
        override val rawValue: Int
): SerializableEnum<Int> {
    THIRTY_SEVEN(37),
    FORTY_TWO(42)
}
```

I can create the mapper simply by:

```
val someEnumMapper = SerializableEnumMapper(SomeEnum.values())  // Works fine
```

But just for the sake of providing a more generic initializer for this, I would like to have something like:

```
val anotherEnumMapper = enumMapperOf<SomeEnum>() // How to do this one?
```

The closest I have been able to come to this:

```
val anotherEnumMapper = enumMapperOf<Int, SomeEnum>() // Still need to provide Int here :(

inline fun <V, reified T> enumMapperOf() where T : Enum<T>, T: SerializableEnum<V> =
        SerializableEnumMapper(enumValues<T>())
```

Is there a way to write this in a way that we need to only provide the `Enum` type and the underlying `Int` type can be implicitly referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `enumMapperOf` is `SerializableEnumMapper<V, T>`. It has two generic type parameters. Though they are related, you can't declare the return type as `SerializableEnumMapper<T.T, T>` (I think this is what you are asking about?), because that's just not a thing. (It is a thing in other languages though.) You do need two type parameters, and relate them with constraints here.

However, if you are happy with using another syntax, you can use this instead:

```
val anotherEnumMapper = enumMapperOf(SomeEnum::class)

inline fun <V, reified T> enumMapperOf(clazz: KClass<T>) where T : Enum<T>, T: SerializableEnum<V> =
    SerializableEnumMapper(enumValues<T>())
```

This allows you to avoid writing `Int`, but introduces a "useless" parameter - it is only used to infer both the generic parameters.

Comment: Yes, the way of having something like `<T.V, T>` was exactly what I was asking for.
Thank you for confirming that my requirement is not possible, and introducing an unused Class parameter to infer the type is the only way possible as of now.

Not really happy with the other syntax, but this is still better than having to specify the different types explicitly.

Comment: "relate them with constraints". It's interesting but confusing that the constraint is specified by adding an unused parameter and relying on type inference. IntelliJ even suggests removing the `clazz` parameter, which means you have to go back to specifying both generic parameters when you call the function.